# I want to install two dimmers on tied neutrals

Tags: electrical

I want to install two dimmers that require neutrals. Currently, the box has 3 neutrals tied together. Could I split them up to use for each dimmer?

Comment: Hearing a lack of understanding of fundamental wiring principles makes me suggest you should hire a professional. What you are looking to do is a very simple project that's often done DIY, but mistakes from incorrectly wiring can be dangerous, possibly fatal.

Comment: In most cases all connected neutrals go back to the same breaker, but you should find out what they come from before trying to install.  But to the point: how many switches are there right now?  You can't install 2 dimmers if there's only one hot line going out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you would be keeping those neutrals together, and also adding the dimmer neutrals to that group so they are all together.  That would be a configuration one would expect:

- neutral from the supply (service panel, consumer unit etc.)
- neutral to lamp 1
- neutral to lamp 2
- neutral to dimmer 1
- neutral to dimmer 2

Generally, neutrals stay together.  But not always.  One place they don't is GFCI outlets.